# Qt 5.12 QML, select QML object by var in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I wonder if there is a way to select an already created QML object with a specific `id` or `objectName` in a javascript function by var (the var is a string parameter corresponding to the QML object id or name).
Eg:

```
// main.qml

ApplicationWindow {

    RoundButton {
        id: btn1
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: btn2
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: btn3
    }

    // ...

    function foo(qmlObjectNameOrId) {
        qmlObjectNameOrId.text = "qmlObjectNameOrId is already in the document and has a property text that I want to set";

        // Qt.findQmlObject(id) would have been great !
    }
}
```

The `Qt.createQmlObject` is not a solution as I want to use already created QML objects.

In C++, the way to achieve this is to use `QQmlApplicationEngine` object and then use the QML root object to perform the selection by QML object name :

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QString objectName = someFunction();

    QObject* qmlObject = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QObject*>(objectName);

    // use your qmlObject ...
}
```

The javascript function would be called in C++ with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(appWindow, "foo", Q_ARG(QVariant, "bar"));`

Thanks

**[EDIT 1] Attempt to Roman Sverdlov answer:**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    objectName: "appWindow"
    // ...

    Pane {
        id: buttonsContainer
        objectName: "buttonsContainer"

        property string  disposition         : "circular_1"
        property int     btnWidth            : 130
        property int     btnHeight           : 130
        property int     btnIconWidth        : 40
        property int     btnIconHeight       : 40
        property int     btnRadius           : btnWidth / 2
        property int     btnMargin           : 40
        property int     btnZ                : 4
        property int     btnPressedBackground: Material.Purple

        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: instructionContainer.bottom
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        visible: false

        Image {
            id: background
            height: buttonsContainer.height - 100
            x: (buttonsContainer.width - width) / 2
            y: (buttonsContainer.height - height) / 2
            source: "qrc:///images/circle_background.png"
            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: topLeft
            color: Material.color(Material.Red)
            x: 0
            z: 1
            height: parent.height / 2
            width: parent.width / 2
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: topRight
            color: Material.color(Material.Green)
            x: parent.width / 2
            z: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            height: parent.height / 2
            width: parent.width / 2
        }

        Label {
            id: backgroundTextTop
            text: "MONTER"
            font.pixelSize: 40
            x: (parent.width - width) / 2
            y: (parent.height - height) / 2 - 50
            z: 2
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: bottomLeft
            color: Material.color(Material.Green)
            x: 0
            z: 1
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            height: parent.height / 2
            width: parent.width / 2
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: bottomRight
            color: Material.color(Material.Red)
            x: parent.width / 2
            z: 1
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            height: parent.height / 2
            width: parent.width / 2
        }

        Label {
            id: backgroundTextBottom
            text: "PLONGER"
            font.pixelSize: 40
            x: (parent.width - width) / 2
            y: (parent.height - height) / 2 + 200
            z: 2
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB1MB
            objectName: "btnB1MB"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B1MB);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B1MB);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB4MT
            objectName: "btnB4MT"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B4MT);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B4MT);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB3MB
            objectName: "btnB3MB"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B3MB);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B3MB);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB4PB
            objectName: "btnB4PB"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B4PB);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B4PB);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB2MT
            objectName: "btnB2MT"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B2MT);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B2MT);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB1PT
            objectName: "btnB1PT"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B1PT);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B1PT);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB2PB
            objectName: "btnB2PB"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B2PB);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B2PB);
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: btnB3PT
            objectName: "btnB3PT"
            width: buttonsContainer.btnWidth
            height: buttonsContainer.btnHeight
            radius: buttonsContainer.btnRadius
            z: buttonsContainer.btnZ
            display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            onPressed: {
                TestsRun.pressButton(Buttons.B3PT);
            }
            onReleased: {
                TestsRun.releaseButton(Buttons.B3PT);
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            setButtonsPosition(buttonsContainer.disposition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a QML element by objectName property
     *
     * @todo Not working
     *
     * @param {String} objectName - The QML object name to get
     */
    function getQmlObjectByName(objectName) {
        console.log("buttonsContainer.children.length", buttonsContainer.children.length);
        return getQmlObjectByNameRecursive(buttonsContainer, objectName)
    }

    /**
     * Get a QML element by objectName property
     *
     * @todo Not working
     *
     * @param {Object} object - The QML object to find the QML element in
     * @param {String} objectName - The QML object name to get
     */
    function getQmlObjectByNameRecursive(object, objectName) {
        for (let child in object.children) {
            console.log(object.children[child].objectName);

            if (object.children[child].objectName === objectName) {
                console.log('found');
                return object.children[child];
            }

            if (typeof object.children[child].children !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('children', object.children[child]);
                return getQmlObjectByNameRecursive(object.children[child], objectName);
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
qml: buttonsContainer.children.length 2
qml: Pane
qml: children QQuickContentItem(0x55c4e2a145d0, "Pane")
qml: 
qml: children QQuickImage(0x55c4e2a1cc80)
qml: undefined
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot use the direct QML id in js because the id is built with a parameter given by the js function called in C++.

Comment: Hi again, my apologies for misunderstanding your question. I've cleaned up your question a bit. (Thanks also for adding more context.) Additionally, I've found these relevant posts: [Find a QML Object by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206813/how-to-find-qml-item-by-its-string-id). [Find a QML Object by Object Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065113/how-to-get-object-by-objectname-in-qml-from-javascript).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think there is a solution to this problem and it is considered an "anti pattern" in Qt.
I just wanted to make my QML more compact and minimalist with some meta programming but it doesn't seem to be allowed with Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by iterating over a QML container which I want to find the QML object by objectName property in.

Thanks to **Roman Sverdlov**, the "DOM traversal" is done with the `contentChildren` property and not `children` property.

```js
    /**
     * Get a QML element by objectName property in buttonsContainer container
     *
     * @param {String} objectName - The QML object name to get
     */
    function getQmlObjectByName(objectName) {
        for (let child in buttonsContainer.contentChildren) {
            if (buttonsContainer.contentChildren[child].objectName === objectName) {
                return buttonsContainer.contentChildren[child];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wow, this is such a bad design for the framework...

Answer (score 1):

if you have `objectName` property set for your objects then you can use something like

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: appWin
RoundButton {
    id: btn1
    objectName: "btn1"
}

RoundButton {
    id: btn2
    objectName: "btn2"
}

// ...

function foo(objectName) {
    for(var child in appWin.children) {
        if(appWin.children[child].objectName === objectName) {
            appWin.children[child].text = "qmlObjectNameOrId is already in the document and has a property text that I want to set";
            break
        }
    }
}
```

}

Of course it looks ugly, but if you need it a lot...

Comment: Not so ugly, I didn't know I could traverse the QML like a DOM in HTML with javascript. I'm going to test this and update the question if it works.

Comment: the `appWin` has no property `children`, `console.log(appWin.children) === undefined`

Comment: Then I think only Item can have children. So try to put your buttons inside some item , e.g. ColumnLayout and repeat

Comment: Seems like the container does not have all the children in its children property... I'll post the attempt to you solution with the code in the question